# Angular 2 dropdown validation not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a template driven form with select dropdown and submit button. When I click on submit button, it shows dropdown required validation message, but it also submits the form.
It shows form is valid in submit function.
as below code

```
<form  #f="ngForm"   name="eventForm" id="eventForm"  #eventForm="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="f.valid && saveForm(eventForm, $event)" novalidate>
<div class="form-group" >
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label for="select_store" class=" control-label">Select Package</label>
      <select  multiple tabindex="10"  name="package_id" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"   #package_id='ngModel'  tabindex="4"   required id="package_id" [(ngModel)]="event.content.package_id"   >
        <option *ngFor="let pk of listDetails" value="{{pk.id}}">{{pk.name}}</option>
      </select>
       <small style="color:red" *ngIf="(eventForm._submitted && !package_id.valid && !eventForm.package_id) || (!package_id.valid && package_id.dirty) ">Content required.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
saveForm(form:NgForm, event: Event) {
  console.log(form.valid)     
   event.preventDefault();

}
```

So how to prevent form submitting and make dropdown validation in a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` will lead `select` to be an element which doesn't 
 belong to `form`.

After removing it from `select`, if there is no option selected, then `f.valid` will turn `false`, form will not be submitted if you attend to submit the form.

refer **[Plinker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FrlQ7Cvz9FYFauVSN1SY)**.